# How to prevent map click event esri map js API?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, events

I have a map and I'm listening a click event like this,

```
 currentMap.on("click",this.identifyMapFeature.bind(this));
```

At some extent I want to disable the click event from map, I've tried these 3 methods from esri js API docs,

```
    this.currentMap.disableMapNavigation();
    this.currentMap.disablePan();
    this.currentMap.disableScrollWheelZoom();
```

but still click event is firing , is there any method like `disableMapClick()` to disable map click ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dojo/on's [pausable](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#pausable) method to pause and resume any type of event. You will have to add the "dojo/on" module in your require statement.

```
require(["dojo/on"], function(on){
  var buttonHandler = on.pausable(button, "click", clickHandler);

  on(disablingButton, "click", function(){
    buttonHandler.pause();
  });

  on(enablingButton, "click", function(){
    buttonHandler.resume();
  });
});
```